# Can I use a FOR OF loop to iterate over an Ember.data array?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

One of the things that confuses me about ember is what syntax I can use with its models particularly Array like structures. Can I replace this function with a FOR OF loop?

```
this.model.foo.forEach(function (baa) {
  types.push(baa.get("type"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Native JS arrays in Ember are padded with extra goodness using the `NativeArray` mixin (see [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.NativeArray.html)) unless you explicitly turn that functionality off.

> The NativeArray mixin contains the properties needed to make the native Array support Ember.MutableArray and all of its dependent APIs. Unless you have Ember.EXTEND_PROTOTYPES or Ember.EXTEND_PROTOTYPES.Array set to false, **this will be applied automatically**. Otherwise you can apply the mixin at anytime by calling Ember.NativeArray.activate

So, for example, you can `filter` your native array by a property value if you wish as well as use the `for of` functionality the native array already has.

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var ar = [ 
      { name: 'red'}, 
      { name: 'yellow'}, 
      { name: 'blue'}
    ];

    for(a of ar){
      console.log(a.name);
    }

    return ar.filterBy("name", "red");
  }
});
```

Working demo [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/warowe/2/edit?html,js,console,output)

Answer (score 0):

I find that if a property is a relation, you can't use "for of" and must resort to using forEach. However, any Ember or native arrays, as Kalman mentioned, should be iterable using it.

Comment: I dislike non-native arrays .